# Return Sublist of Singly Linked List Recursively

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to return the sublist of a singly linked list recursively.

Ex. list = 3->4->5->None

sub(list, 1, 2) should return 4->5

param 1 - start index

param 2 - length of sublist

I am having a little trouble as my code only returns the last element of the sublist and not the whole sublist.

```
def sub(list, start, length) -> Node:
    if list is None:
        return None
    elif start <= 0:
        if length ==1:
            list.next = None
            return list
        else:
            return sub(list.next, start - 1, length - 1)
    else:

        return sub(list.next, start - 1, length)
```

Comment: You perhaps should include more of your code.  'yield' and 'yield from' may be better than 'return' here.  Linked lists in python are Much slower than the built in list type for many operations, and what you need would be just a slice with the built in list type.   Using a variable called 'list' will mask the constructor for the built in list type - 'list_' or 'lst' would be better.

Comment: BTW, if you use 'yield', you don't need your callable to be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter in your `sub` function that stores the accumulated sub list as you traverse the main structure:

```
def sub(lst, s, e, c = 0, new_l = None):
   if c >= e:
      return new_l
   if lst is None:
      raise IndexError('index out of bounds')
   return sub(lst.next, s, e, c = c+1, new_l = None if c + 1 <= s else getattr(new_l, 'add_node', Lst)(lst.value))
```

---

`Lst` implemenation:

```
class Lst:
   def __init__(self, val=None):
      self.value, self.next = val, None
   def add_node(self, val):
      if self.value is None:
         self.value = val
      elif self.next is None:
         self.next = Lst(val)
      else:
         self.next.add_node(val)
      return self
   def __repr__(self):
      return f'{self.value}{"" if self.next is None else " -> "+repr(self.next)}'


l = Lst()
for i in range(10):
   l.add_node(i)

print(sub(l, 0, 4))
print(sub(l, 2, 7))
print(sub(l, 5, 12))
```

Output:

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in sub
  [Previous line repeated 7 more times]
File "<stdin>", line 5, in sub
IndexError: index out of bounds
```